# get all records with uniq attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Hi I have two associated models,

```
class Take_away < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :restaurant
end
class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :take_aways
end
```

I want to select one take away record for each restaurant I saw some one was using code like this

```
TakeAway.uniq.pluck(:restaurant_id)
```

but this returns me a number array like

```
[3, 1, 2]
```

I want active records objects of TakeAway how can I get my expected result?. I am using rails 4.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

You need to try this

```
TakeAway.distinct(:restaurant_id)
```